# IOS How much an attacker can see about my method?

Tags: ios, iphone, security, gdb

I know that an attacker with GDB attached to an app can extract many informations about my code. He can also force the return of a method and modify the behaviour of the app. Anyway there's something i haven't understood.
If i have a method like this :

```
-(int)example_method :(int)parameter_1 :(int)parameter_2{

    int value_1=300;
    int value_2=1240445;
    int sub_result_1 = parameter_1*parameter_2;
    int sub_result_2 = parameter_1*value_1;
    int sub_result_3 = value_1*value_2;
    int result = sub_result_1+sub_result_2+sub_result_3;

    return result;
}
```

For what i know an attacker in GDB can extract and manipulate:

1. the value of parameter_1
2. the value of parameter_2
3. the value of result

My question is, can an attacker see how the result is made ?
Can he see those lines inside the method?

```
int value_1=300;
int value_2=1240445;
int sub_result_1 = parameter_1*parameter_2;
int sub_result_2 = parameter_1*value_1;
int sub_result_3 = value_1*value_2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attacker using gdb can see your code... At least at assembly level

If your program is compiled with debug symbols (`-g`) then it is possible to associate the program with its source code.

If the program is compiled without them, the debugger will still be able to see the assembly instructions of your code. Note that assembly is very low level thus will lack a lot of informations (variable names, high level source code, ...). But with some assembly knowledge, it is possible to reverse engineer the binary to see what operation is performed.

This reverse engineering process can be made harder with [obfuscation techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)).

---

> My question is, can an attacker see how the result is made ? Can he see those lines inside the method?

There is no concept of variable in assembly, only registers. Sometimes a register will be associated to a variable, and sometimes the assembly will be very be different from what you wrote, especially with obfuscation.

The algorithm have only to be *functionally identical*, but assembly is really different from higher-level languages thus don't expect 1-1 matching.

Note that your program can be reverse engineered without knowing exactly which variable is used. Depending the program size and complexity it can be trivial or extremely complex.

If you want to see what contains your program at assembly level you can use command like `objdump -d -S`.